# Nginx redirect http to https and remove trailing slashes with one single redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I want to redirect http to https and remove trailing slashes in nginx with one single redirect. The solution I have today is the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

The problem with this solution is that it will give two redirects

Gives Two redirects:

```
http://www.example.com/test/ --> http://www.example.com/test
http://www.example.com/test --> https://www.example.com/test
```

Is it possible to make a solution where you only get one single redirect like bellow?

```
http://www.example.com/test/ --> https://www.example.com/test
```

when I looked through the documentation of nginx rewrite and return methods I felt like it should be possible to do it with a single rewrite somehow:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
```

But nothing I have tried have given me the correct results.

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/(.*)/$ https://$host/$1 permanent;`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for a fast reply and correct answer! Add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already had the components of a correct solution. Use the scheme and hostname, together with the capture to construct the destination URL:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ https://$host/$1 permanent;
```

Comment: What about redirect to also include `www` replacement. Example redirect `http://www.website.com` -> `https://website.com/`. Three things are accomplished: https is added, www is removed, and trailing slash is added.